# Dynamic SQL and Cursor related issue

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I have declared cursor and used in the procedure body, then I have dynamic sql statement which creates a table on the fly. After that I need to access the same cursor which i declared.

When I try to open the cursor before the execution of dynamic sql statement its working fine.

When I try to open the cursor after the execution of dynamic sql statement its not opening and cursor.

Please help me.

Thank you.

```
   create or replace procedure(columns varchar2)
   is
   column_names varchar2(100);
   sql_query varchar2(200);
   begin
       select pk_cols into column_names
       from rules where rule_column=columns;

       sql_query:='create global temporary table ('||column_names||')';
       execute immediate sql_query;
   end;
```

Comment: Why do you need to create a table on the fly? Usually, in Oracle, you don't have to do that, but use a temporary table instead.

Comment: Yah, Iam creating a temporary table.

Comment: Usually, in Oracle, you create a temporary table only once and re-use that (unlike in SQL server, where it's common to create and drop tables on the fly). Why do you need to create the table on the fly? Are the columns unknown until run time?

Comment: @Frank Schmitt - Yes, the column names are unknown until rum time. But, when other user will run the stored procedure then it gets error like table already exists. Then, what should we do for this ?

Comment: Could you please post an example (procedure input, DDL statement you generate to create the table, expected output) of what you're trying to accomplish? This sounds like you don't need a temporary table at all (only a cursor with a dynamically generated statement)

Comment: @Frank Schmitt - I have edited my post, please check it and suggest me how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Creating the table is DDL which in Oracle results in an implicit commit, ending your transaction.

To solve this problem you could create the table inside an autonomous transaction:

```
  -- open cursor

  declare
    pragma autonomous_transaction;
  begin
    execute immediate 'create table ...';
  end;

  -- do more with your cursor
```

For more information about autonomous transactions, see [this overview](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/autonomous-transactions.php) on Tim Hall's excellent site.

Comment: t Hart - Its not working, as you said I kept autonomous_transaction in declaration section. But same issue. I am wondering why its not opening the cursor. Please help, Trying from 7 hrs.